# PowerShell ImportExcel Module Performance Issues

Tags: excel, powershell, import

I would like to know what, in an excel file, make import-excel slower. I have an excel file with 37 columns and 43 rows. When I perform an Import-Excel on this data set, it takes almost 35 seconds to complete. I have then tried to copy/paste all the data in a fresh new excel file and it took PowerShell only 131 milliseconds to import the same data set. I was wondering would be the root cause of the slowness in the first file.

**Might it be the size, formulas and conditional formatting that make    one file more difficult to import that the other?**

| FILE #1 | FILE #2 |
| --- | --- |
| Data formatted in a table | Data formatted in a table |
| Has several sheets | Has one sheet |
| Used to macro enabled .xlsm but converted into a .xlsx and macros removed | Is .xlsx |
| Has conditional formatting | Has no conditional formatting |
| Has Index/Match formulas | Has no formulas |
| Created with Excel 365 | Created with Excel 365 |
| 24KB | 9054KB |

**FILE #1**

```
Measure-Command {$DataSet = Import-Excel -Path $ExcelTest -WorkSheetname SheetTest -DataOnly}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 34
Milliseconds      : 499
Ticks             : 344990818
TotalDays         : 0,000399294928240741
TotalHours        : 0,00958307827777778
TotalMinutes      : 0,574984696666667
TotalSeconds      : 34,4990818
TotalMilliseconds : 34499,0818
```

**FILE #2**

```
Measure-Command {$DataSet = Import-Excel -Path $TestExcel -WorkSheetname $TestSheet -DataOnly}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 131
Ticks             : 1310119
TotalDays         : 1,51634143518519E-06
TotalHours        : 3,63921944444444E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0,00218353166666667
TotalSeconds      : 0,1310119
TotalMilliseconds : 131,0119
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with **FILE #1** was the size but I was not sure why. I tried to copy the whole sheet to a new excel and started removing formulas and conditional formatting but nothing changed. Then, by googling about this, I have found this web page that explained what might cause an inflated excel size: https://chrismenardtraining.com/post/excel-file-size-out-of-control-learn-how-to-reduce-excel-spreadsheet-file-size

Long story short, even though my excel file only had 43 rows with data, the last row recognized by excel (CTRL + end) was row: 1.047.611

This make Import-Excel very slow since it probably went through the whole thing.

I just did the following:

- Selected the last column > pressed together **CTRL + SHIFT + RIGHT
  ARROW** to select all columns to the right of the last one >
  right-click > **Delete**
- Selected the last raw with data (43) > pressed
  together **CTRL + SHIFT + DOWN ARROW** to select all rows below the last
  one with data > right-click > **Delete**

**Result:**

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 411
Ticks             : 4117167
TotalDays         : 4,76523958333333E-06
TotalHours        : 0,00011436575
TotalMinutes      : 0,006861945
TotalSeconds      : 0,4117167
TotalMilliseconds : 411,7167
```